# Why we need Hermitian conjugate amplitude rather than complex conjugate amplitude for calculating cross section?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, complex-numbers, s-matrix-theory

I am trying to understand some concepts related to scattering in QED, so I would phrase my question in similar context.

After calculating the scattering amplitude $\mathcal{M}$ for a process, we take its square for finding differential cross-section. But it seems that we need to trace over all the matrices involved in the expression of $\mathcal{M}$. Or alternatively, we define the Hermitian conjugate amplitude $\mathcal{M}^{\dagger}$ so that we can get a number by multiplying $\mathcal{M}$ $\mathcal{M}^{\dagger}$.
( See equation 13.56 in *Matthew D. Schwartz* for example ).

My question is: **Why we need to define $\mathcal{M}^{\dagger}$ ( or take the trace )? Can't we just multiply $\mathcal{M}$ with its complex conjugate?**

In my understanding, $\mathcal{M}$ is a number itself ( not a matrix or vector) because it's an amplitude. I would appreciate any comment or answer that illuminates this concept.

[ I think it has do with multiple in and out states/polarizations, but I am not able to see it. ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that $\mathcal{M}$ is, technically, just a number (a scalar), which is why it has no indices.

However, it is *composed* of matrices, vectors, and spinors. And using $\mathcal{M}^\dagger$ allows you to perform operations on the matrices *inside* $\mathcal{M}$, e.g. $$(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{c})^\ast = (\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{c})^\dagger = \mathbf{c}^\dagger\cdot \mathbf{B}^\dagger\cdot \mathbf{a}^\dagger, $$
where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{B}$ a matrix. So the results is a scalar in both cases, but maybe you already have the transposed vectors/matrices so it's easier to compute it when expressed as in the last term.

An example of a matrix element for $e^- e^+ \rightarrow \mu^- \mu^+$ is something like:
$$ \mathcal{M} = \frac{\mathrm{i}e^2}{s^2} \underbrace{\bar u_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_1, \lambda_1) \gamma^\mu v_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_2, \lambda_2)}_{\text{incoming muons}}\cdot\underbrace{\bar v_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_2, \lambda'_2) \gamma_\mu u_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_1, \lambda'_1)}_{\text{outgoing electrons}},$$
with $s$ being the centre of mass energy, $\mathbf{q,p}$ the momenta, and $\lambda$s the helicities. The $\mu$ or $e$ in brackets refer to the particles (muons or electrons), while the $\mu$ on the gamma matrices are indices.

Now, $\bar u = u^\dagger \gamma^0$ is a $4\times1$ row vector, $\gamma^\mu$ is also a $4\times 4$ matrix, and $v$ is a $1\times 4$ column vector. So you could perform brute force matrix multiplication and get a $1\times 1$ a scalar.

However, there exist useful relations of the form $$ \sum_{\lambda=\pm 1}u_\alpha(\mathbf{p}, \lambda) \bar u^\beta (\mathbf{q}, \lambda),$$
where the spinors $u$'s refer to the *same* particle ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ here are the indices of the spinor). The result is then related to traces of gamma matrices, spinors, and momenta.

Bottom line, to make your life easier, you would like to end with an expression that includes $u_{(\mu)}\bar u_{(\mu)}$ and $v_{(e)}\bar v_{(e)}$ so that you can use the trace relations.

An easy way to get these is by expressing $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ as $\mathcal{M} \mathcal{M}^\dagger$ which, for the example above, would be:
$$\frac{\mathrm{i}e^2}{s^2} \bar v_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_2, \lambda_2)\gamma^\nu u_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_1, \lambda_1)\bar u_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_1, \lambda_1)\gamma^\mu v_{(\mu)}(\mathbf{q}_2, \lambda_2)\\ \bar u_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_1, \lambda'_1)\gamma_\nu v_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_2, \lambda'_2) \bar v_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_2, \lambda'_2)\gamma_{\mu}v_{(e)}(\mathbf{p}_1, \lambda'_1).$$